Minimize, maximize, close buttons on the Gnome's top bar
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 with the latest Gnome, and I am trying to make some use for the top panel which stays there just for some icons and nothing else.
Remembering the Unity desktop, which still exists with some kind of limitations like (maybe?) missing Wayland or missing some features or options, I was wondering if it's possible to maximize an app and have on the top bar: the windows commands like min/maximize/close and, eventually, the global menu. I've found some very old articles on the web which are confusing or not updated, so I thought to ask here in case anybody has any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

24.04 is not yet released

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Actively maintained for many years, the Gnome Shell extension Unite by hardpixel can include the window control buttons in the top bar and display the title of the window. For applications with a "legacy" (server side) title bar, the title bar is merged with the top bar when the application is maximized. As an added bonus, it has a "No annoyance" function build right in (immediately focuses a window instead of showing a "Your Window is Ready" notification. It also can show a system tray.
For some time, the developer has refused to continue publishing any longer on extensions.gnome.org, but you could still install an updated version directly from the GitHub repository. For now, it is available again on extensions.gnome.org.
Having a global menu on the top bar is less easy. There has been projects attempting to achieve that, but none has proceeded. Likely, the interest is also lower because there is an increasing tendency to move away from the traditional pull down menu.

I understand your point now! That worked, but it's also useless since we have some sort of "hamburgers" nowadays, so it doesn't really save any other space.
In case someone is seeing this and wants to install Unite: remember to rename the folder with the same name of the UUID.
For the rest, I hope that Hide Top Bar will be available again and, in the meantime, I'll just use Unity DE. It's the only one that makes sense for my usage until KDE 6 becomes less CPU hungry with the kwin_wayland.

Didn't complain about it, I actually said you were right. Thanks for helping and for explaining how to accept the answer as a resolution.
